# How do I get the current and next greater value in one select?

Tags: mysql, innodb, select

I have a InnoDB table 'idtimes' (MySQL 5.0.22-log) 
with columns

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`time` int(20) NOT NULL, [...]
```

with a compound unique key

```
UNIQUE KEY `id_time` (`id`,`time`)
```

so there can be multiple timestamps per id and multiple ids per timestamp.

I'm trying to set up a query where I get all entries plus the next greater time for each entry, if it exists, so it should return e.g.:

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| id  | time       | nexttime   |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 155 | 1300000000 | 1311111111 |
| 155 | 1311111111 | 1322222222 |
| 155 | 1322222222 |       NULL |
| 156 | 1312345678 | 1318765432 |
| 156 | 1318765432 |       NULL |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

Right now I am so far:

```
SELECT l.id, l.time, r.time FROM 
    idtimes AS l LEFT JOIN idtimes AS r ON l.id = r.id
    WHERE l.time < r.time ORDER BY l.id ASC, l.time ASC;
```

but of course this returns all rows with r.time > l.time and not only the first one...

I guess I'll need a subselect like

```
SELECT outer.id, outer.time, 
    (SELECT time FROM idtimes WHERE id = outer.id AND time > outer.time 
        ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1)
    FROM idtimes AS outer ORDER BY outer.id ASC, outer.time ASC;
```

but I don't know how to refer to the current time (I know the above is not valid SQL).

How do I do this with a single query (and I'd prefer not to use @variables that depend on stepping though the table one row at a time and remembering the last value)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Doing a JOIN is one thing you might need.

```
SELECT l.id, l.time, r.time FROM 
    idtimes AS l LEFT JOIN idtimes AS r ON l.id = r.id
```

I suppose the outer join is deliberate, and you want to be getting nulls.  More on that later.

```
WHERE l.time < r.time ORDER BY l.id ASC, l.time ASC;
```

You only want the r. row that has the lowest (MIN) time that is higher than the l.time.  That is the place where you need subquerying.

```
WHERE r.time = (SELECT MIN(time) FROM idtimes r2 where r2.id = l.id AND r2.time > l.time)
```

Now to the nulls.  If "there is no next-higher time", then the SELECT MIN() will evaluate to null (or worse), and that itself never compares equal to anything, so your WHERE clause will never be satisfied, and the "highest time" for each ID, could never appear in the result set.

You solve it by eliminating your JOIN, and moving the scalar subquery into the SELECT list :

```
SELECT id, time, 
    (SELECT MIN(time) FROM idtimes sub 
        WHERE sub.id = main.id AND sub.time > main.time) as nxttime
  FROM idtimes AS main
```

Answer (score 7):

**I always avoid to use subqueries** either in `SELECT` block or in the `FROM` block, because it makes the code "dirtier" and sometimes less efficient.

I think a more elegant way to do it is to:

### 1. Find the *times* greater than the *time* of the row

You can do this with a `JOIN` between *idtimes* table with itself, constraining the join to the same *id* and to *times* greater than the *time* of current row.

You should use `LEFT JOIN` to avoid excluding rows where there are no *times* greater than the one of the current row.

```
SELECT
    i1.id,
    i1.time AS time,
    i2.time AS greater_time
FROM
    idtimes AS i1
    LEFT JOIN idtimes AS i2 ON i1.id = i2.id AND i2.time > i1.time
```

The problem, as you mentioned, is that you have multiple rows where *next_time* is greater than *time*.

```
+-----+------------+--------------+
| id  | time       | greater_time |
+-----+------------+--------------+
| 155 | 1300000000 | 1311111111   |
| 155 | 1300000000 | 1322222222   |
| 155 | 1311111111 | 1322222222   |
| 155 | 1322222222 |       NULL   |
| 156 | 1312345678 | 1318765432   |
| 156 | 1318765432 |       NULL   |
+-----+------------+--------------+
```

### 2. Find the rows where *greater_time* is not only greater but *next_time*

The best way to filter all of these useless rows is to find out if there are *times* between *time* (greater than) and *greater_time* (lesser than) for this *id*.

```
SELECT
    i1.id,
    i1.time AS time,
    i2.time AS next_time,
    i3.time AS intrudor_time
FROM
    idtimes AS i1
    LEFT JOIN idtimes AS i2 ON i1.id = i2.id AND i2.time > i1.time
    LEFT JOIN idtimes AS i3 ON i2.id = i3.id AND i3.time > i1.time AND i3.time < i2.time
```

ops, we still have a **false next_time**!

```
+-----+------------+--------------+---------------+
| id  | time       | next_time    | intrudor_time |
+-----+------------+--------------+---------------+
| 155 | 1300000000 | 1311111111   |         NULL  |
| 155 | 1300000000 | 1322222222   |    1311111111 |
| 155 | 1311111111 | 1322222222   |         NULL  |
| 155 | 1322222222 |       NULL   |         NULL  |
| 156 | 1312345678 | 1318765432   |         NULL  |
| 156 | 1318765432 |       NULL   |         NULL  |
+-----+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Just filter the rows where this event happens, adding the `WHERE` constraint below

```
WHERE
    i3.time IS NULL
```

Voilà, we have what we need!

```
+-----+------------+--------------+---------------+
| id  | time       | next_time    | intrudor_time |
+-----+------------+--------------+---------------+
| 155 | 1300000000 | 1311111111   |         NULL  |
| 155 | 1311111111 | 1322222222   |         NULL  |
| 155 | 1322222222 |       NULL   |         NULL  |
| 156 | 1312345678 | 1318765432   |         NULL  |
| 156 | 1318765432 |       NULL   |         NULL  |
+-----+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I hope that you still need an answer after 4 years!

Comment: That's clever. I'm not sure it's easier to understand though. I think that if we replaced the `is null` and the join to i3 with `where not exists (select 1 from itimes i3 where [same clause])`, then the code would more closely reflect what we want to express.

Answer (score 2):

Before presenting the solution, I should note it is not pretty. It would be much easier if you had some `AUTO_INCREMENT` column on your table (do you?)

```
SELECT 
  l.id, l.time, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(r.time ORDER BY r.time), ',', 1)
FROM 
  idtimes AS l 
  LEFT JOIN idtimes AS r ON (l.id = r.id)
WHERE 
  l.time < r.time
GROUP BY
  l.id, l.time
```

Explanation:

- Same join as yours: join two tables, the right one only gets the higher times
- GROUP BY both columns from left table: this ensures we get all `(id, time)` combinations (which are also known to be unique).
- For each `(l.id, l.time)`, get the *first* `r.time` which is greater than `l.time`. This happens with first ordering the `r.time`s via `GROUP_CONCAT(r.time ORDER BY r.time)`, the by slicing first token via `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.

Good luck, and, don't expect good performance if this table is large.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get what you want from a `min()` and `GROUP BY` with no inner select:

```
SELECT l.id, l.time, min(r.time) 
FROM idtimes l 
LEFT JOIN idtimes r on (r.id = l.id and r.time > l.time)
GROUP BY l.id, l.time;
```

I would *almost* bet a large sum of money that the optimiser turns this into the same thing as Erwin Smout's answer anyway, and it's debatable whether it's any clearer, but there it is for completeness...

Comment: For what its worth, SSMS & SQLServer 2016 liked your query a lot more than Erwin's (2s runtime versus 24s runtime on ~24k result set)

Comment: Andrew seems like you've lost the bet :-)

Comment: Interesting, because it should be a general case that a subquery that joins back to the outer query table by one of the PK columns is the same as a group by. I wonder if any other databases would optimise it better. (I know very little about database optimizers BTW; just being curious.)